# How can I map keys, looking them up in another dict?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given these dictionaries:

```yaml
somedict:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
otherdict:
  key1: mapped1
  key2: mapped2
```

How can I map `somedict`, changing its keys by looking them up in `otherdict` in Ansible? The result should be this:

```yaml
mapped1: value1
mapped2: value2
```

It seems it should be doable with something declarative of this sort:

```
{{ somedict | map(<MAP KEY>) | list }}
```

Or do I really have to use an imperative loop for this kind of thing?

The following

```
{{ somedict | map('extract', otherdict) | list }}
```

successfully maps the keys, but it loses the values in the process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: "*The result should be this:*"

```yaml
mapped1: value1
mapped2: value2
```

A: The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ somedict|
                 map('extract', otherdict)|
                 zip(somedict|
                     dict2items|
                     map(attribute='value'))|
                 list }}"
```

gives a list of lists. This is not the expected result

```yaml
  msg:
  - - mapped1
    - value1
  - - mapped2
    - value2
```

To receive a dictionary, apply the *dict* function and remove the *list* filter. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(somedict|
                      map('extract', otherdict)|
                      zip(somedict|
                          dict2items|
                          map(attribute='value'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    mapped1: value1
    mapped2: value2
```

This can be further simplified. The task below gives the same dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(somedict|
                      map('extract', otherdict)|
                      zip(somedict.values())) }}"
```

---

Notes

- Conversion of a dictionary to list results in the list of dictionary keys. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ somedict|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - key1
  - key2
```

- The same result can be achieved by the listing of dictionary keys

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ somedict.keys()|list }}"
```